# why does this error occurs while using selenium chromedriver?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

C:\Users\abhi1702\Desktop\selenium\venv\Scripts\python.exe

```
C:/Users/abhi1702/Desktop/selenium/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhi1702\Desktop\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\abhi1702\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\abhi1702\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abhi1702/Desktop/selenium/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    chrome= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Users\abhi1702\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\abhi1702\Desktop\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\abhi1702\Desktop\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Aryan, welcome on Stack overflow! Please format code in your question using formating tools.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in probably your post:

```
Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH
```

So please try adding chromedriver.exe to your system variable PATH.

For Windows, open System Properties - Environment Variables - and modify System variable "PATH": click Edit, add new entry with path to chromedriver.exe, for example: *C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe*